# How to move SOLR from normal 8983 port to Apache Tomcat 7 Server in ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, solr, tomcat7

I have Installed Tomcat 7 in usr/shared/tomcat7 folder. After that installed Solr 4.7 in /var/www/ folder in my ubuntu. My solr is now running on http://localhost:8983/solr/ url, but I want to move it now to tomcat server and want to access it by http://localhost:8080/solr/ url.

What to do? Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Solr with Jetty that comes with Solr and just change the port number in jetty.xml file. If you want to use Solr with Tomcat you need to do more than that. Here's a complete instructions:

1. Install tomcat7 using apt-get

`sudo apt-get install tomcat7`

2. Download solr to /tmp (eg: 4.0.0)

`cd /tmp`

`wget http://{mirror site}/apache/lucene/solr/4.0.0/apache-solr-4.0.0.tgz`

3. Copy solr war file to tomcat webapps. (dist path might have been changed in future versions)

`cp /tmp/apache-solr-4.0.0/dist/apache-solr-4.0.0.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/solr.war`

4. Make a solr home directory

`mkdir /usr/share/solr`

5. Copy everything inside the example solr to new solr home directory.

`cp -R /tmp/apache-solr-4.0.0/example/solr/* /usr/share/solr/`

6. Create a config file inside tomcat for solr and insert following lines.

`sudo pico /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml`

```
    <Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/solr.war" debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true" >
    <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr" override="true" />
    </Context>
```

7. Create the cores
   Creating example core:

   1. Create example directory in /var/lib/solr and copy another conf file from another core like /usr/share/solr/collection1

   `mkdir /var/lib/solr/example`

   `cp -R /usr/share/solr/collection1 /var/lib/solr/example/`

   2. create a data directory for example core and set the  in /var/lib/solr/example/conf/solrconfig.xml
   3. `mkdir /var/lib/solr/data/example`
   4. Give tomcat7 the permissions

   `chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/solr`

   5. To enable the core it needs a symlink in /usr/share/solr

   `ln -s /var/lib/solr/example /usr/share/solr/example`

   6. Add the following core configuration to /usr/share/solr.xml (only  if there is configuration for other cores)

   <solr persistent="false">
     <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" shareSchema="true">
       <core name="example" instanceDir="example" />
     </cores>
   </solr>

7. Solr cores are available at http://HOST_NAME:PORT/solr/admin/cores (http://example.com:8080/)
 8. Add other cores the same way.

9. Change tomcat port from 8080 in /etc/tomcat7/server.xml
10. Security: set solr a password

    a. Open /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml for editing.

    b. Add solr role and users within the  element and save the changes:

    <role rolename="solradmin" />
    <user username="username" password="password" roles="solradmin" />

c. Open /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml for editing. Add the following lines within the  element:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr Lockdown</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>solradmin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Solr</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

d. Save the changes and restart Tomcat (/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart).

e. Access solr using http://username:password@example.com:8080/solr

If tomcat complains about missing libraries like logger copy the required jars to /var/tomcat7/lib

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great solution. I have tried this and I am currently running Solr on Tomcat 7. Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for solution.

http://www.dansolovay.com/2014/06/switching-solr-from-port-8983.html